Cannot resize a partition with Gparted below "Minimum size"
I used gparted to resize a partition successfully, but it does not allow me to shrink it as much as I would actually like.
I think it's because of the Minimum size.

Is there a possibility to reduce the Minimum size value to shrink the partition further than currently allowed?
@Ferrybig:

@oldfred:
sudo parted -L

@Tom Yan:
It says:  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/nvme0n1p3".
Correct: I have LVM on LUKS. But I managed to reduce to Minimum size.
You write: You might need to shrink the PV....
Can you provide a link or explain in detail.
Thanks a lot

What partition type are you trying to modify?

What format is this partition? If NTFS you need to use Windows tools. If LVM, it takes all the space for volumes which it should. Post this in question: sudo parted -l

Please add the output of pvdisplay -m /dev/nvme0n1p3. (It seems that you have LVM on LUKS (or maybe plain dm-crypt, idk) though. I wonder if gparted support shrinking that at all. You might need to shrink the PV and then the "crypt" then the partition step by step manually with appropriate commands respectively.)

This probably indicates that there is data written near the end of the partition. You can attempt to defragment it using:
e4defrag -c /mounted/path

Replace /mounted/path with the mount point of /dev/nvme0n1p3.
As always, make sure to back up all your data before making any operation that will bring changes to your disk.

This is a complete new setup on LinuxMint.
I think defragment will not help

Tried to do your recommendation:
e4defrag /dev/mapper/vgmint-root. Finished successfully.
But the Minimum Size is unchanged.
